# HTML UL LI a href links not working

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am working on a website and for the menu I have the following code:

```
<header>
  <div class="sticky-nav">
    <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul id="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="http://aevidum.com">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Clubs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Campaigns</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Movement</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">The Talk</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">#Aevidum</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

But when I click on the home link it doesn't go anywhere or do anything. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Here is a link to the directory I'm working on it in: http://aevidum.com/brushed/

Comment: Markup looks fine. Works perfectly using only the HTML, without CSS or JS. See: http://jsfiddle.net/y7r9g83k/

Conclusion: Must be the JS.

Comment: Your href path is empty.....

Comment: Think its your JavaScript

Comment: Two listeners (by means of jQuery) are attached to the links. They prevent link from working. `$('#mobile-nav').on('click', function(e){` and so on

Comment: You have a JS error also on that page: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think some java-script or jquery  function is overriding your current  functionality, because the code which you posted works fine without any includes.

```html
<header>
  <div class="sticky-nav">
    <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul id="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="http://aevidum.com">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Clubs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Campaigns</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Movement</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">The Talk</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">#Aevidum</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: yeah, ive come to the same conclusion as well, thanks for a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you may be using the Brushed Template by Alessio Atzeni?

I had the same problem. Below is the full nav section I have, and where I added a class 'linkfix_LogIn' to the link I needed to be not a relative anchor.

```
    <header>
    <div class="sticky-nav">
        <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>

        <div id="logo">
            <a id="goUp" href="#home-slider" title="Home">Home</a>
        </div>

        <nav id="menu">
            <ul id="menu-nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="#home-slider">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#about">What Is This</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                 <li class="linkfix_LogIn"><a href="http://www.YourURL.com">Outside Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>
```

Also in the main.js file, amend the following inside this function:

```
BRUSHED.listenerMenu = function(){
```

And add this little method at the bottom:

```
    // Fix outside links.
    $('.linkfix_LogIn a').on('click',function() {           
        window.location.href = "http://www.YourURL.com";  // Change This
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use "Brushed Template by Alessio Atzeni", It seems to be caused by "plugin.js".

Get "jquery.nav.js" from the following page.
https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

Then overwrite the code of "jQuery One Page Nav Plugin" in the last part of "plugin.js" (near the 30th line to the end) with the contents of "jquery.nav.js".

I was able to solve the same problem in this way.
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This also solves the very same issue in "Vesperr Bootstrap Theme" (https://bootstrapmade.com/vesperr-free-bootstrap-template/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just added `diplay: block` on the a tag. It's worked for me!

```
ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Actually this can be a cause, because <a> may take not all space inside li element but only as much  as takes text

Answer (score 1):

Issue might be with the jquery come with your template. If nothing worked out use a javascript onclick function on the 'href' tag to redirect

```
onclick="window.open('https://www.yoursite.com/mypage')"
```

If you want to mention the target type use this instead

```
onclick="window.open('https://www.yoursite.com/mypage', '_blank')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Proceed like this everything  is gonna work perfectly .

```
    <ul  class="nav-links">
        <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="Tours.html">Tours</a></li>
        <li> <a href="Explore.html">Explore</a> </li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).